# Нахождение наименьшего расстояния между строками и максимального номера строки для уникальных элементов массива

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Требуется вычислить наименьшее расстояние между строками и максимальный номер строки, для каждого уникального элемента массива посредством Pandas и/или Numpy

Исходные данные:

```
Row - номер строки
c1, c2, c3 - столбцы с данными 
Row, c1, c2, c3 
1, 3, 5, 6 
2, 2, 3, 8
3, 5, 4, 9
4, 2, 6, 8
```

Ожидаемый результат

```
Elem, Dist, Row  
2, 2, 4
3, 1, 2
4, 0, 3
5, 2, 3
6, 3, 4
8, 2, 4 
9, 0, 3
```

Доп. условия 
В случае если элемент встречается в массиве не больше одного раза, то значение расстояние для него = 0. Каждая строка содрежит неповторяющиеся элементы.

Comment: Для примера берем число 3. Это число встречается в первой и второй строке.  Расcтояние (Dist) = 2 - 1. Максимальный номер строки в которой встречается это число (Row) = 2. По аналогии для 6.  Dist = row 4-1 = 3. Max (row) = 4.  Только для каждого числа нужно выбрать наименьшее значение Dist.

Comment: На примере  любимых лотерейных шаров (может так проще будет понять). Нужно найти наименьшее расстояние между всеми играми  для каждого шара (числа) и в какой последней игре (номер игры) встречался конкретный шар.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def dist(c):
    if len(c) > 1:
        return c.diff().min()
    else:
        return 0

res = \
(df.set_index('Row')
   .stack()
   .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
   .reset_index(name='elem')
   .groupby('elem')
   ['Row']
   .agg([dist, 'max'])
   .rename(columns={'max':'row'})
   .reset_index())
```

результат:

```
In [355]: res
Out[355]:
   elem  dist  row
0     2     2    4
1     3     1    2
2     4     0    3
3     5     2    3
4     6     3    4
5     8     2    4
6     9     0    3
```